# How to Conditional Return inflater in Volley Request - Android

Tags: android, json, android-studio, android-volley, rootview

i have a problem in Develop Android in Android Studio. when i try to get data with Volley, i have two root to display in fragment android. and I want conditional return for root view.

this my code

```
rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pesanan, container, false);
    rootViewNull = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_pesanan_null, container, false);
    listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
    listPesanan.clear();
    listView.setAdapter(null);

vor = new VolleyObjectResult() {
        @Override
        public void resSuccess(String requestType, JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("1","1");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                String strStatus = response.getString("message");
                if(strStatus.equals("no_data"))
                {
                    strStatusData = "0";

                }else {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        ListPesawatDataSet lds = new ListPesawatDataSet();
                        lds.setId(jsonObject.getString("trx_pemesanan_id"));
                        lds.setInvoice(jsonObject.getString("trx_pemesanan_invoice"));
                        lds.setTotalPrice(jsonObject.getString("trx_pemesanan_order_price"));

                        listPesanan.add(lds);
                    }
                    listPesananAdapter= new ListPesananAdapter(getActivity(), listPesanan);
                    listPesananAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listView.setAdapter(listPesananAdapter);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void resError(String requestType, VolleyError error) {
            //Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Connection problem!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    };
    vos = new VolleyObjectService(vor, getActivity());
    vos.postJsonObject("GETCALL", url2, data);

    return rootView;
```

I Want return rootView to rootViewNull When Response Json Empty / no_data. please help about my trouble.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Instead if returning null as root view, call API first and on its response open your fragment, this would be better way to handle asynchronous response with UI.

Comment: but how can i know data empty or not

Comment: `if(strStatus.equals("no_data"))` you're already checking here about data, do your fragment transaction conditionally. All I'm saying is that, add/replace your fragment once you've got data, don't do otherwise.

Comment: oh i see, but this code scheme has been used in many fragments that I have, it will a lot of effort if I change the scheme for this case to all the fragments I want to condition like this. are there other ways?